# How change background image for each Dojo mobile View?

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

Is it possible to change the background image for each view using Dojo Mobile ?

For instance :

```
<div id="view1" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/View">
 <h1 data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Heading">View 1</h1>
 <ul data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/RoundRectList">
    <li data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ListItem"
      data-dojo-props='icon:"images/i-icon-1.png",
                     moveTo:"view2",
                     transition:"slide"'>Go To View 2</li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div id="view2" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/View">
 <h1 data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Heading"
  data-dojo-props='back:"View 1",
                   moveTo:"view1"'>View 2</h1>
</div>
```

Example here : http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/mobile/View.html

If I put something like 
    style="background-image: url(../images/test-background.png) in the div section of view1, only the div will be backgrounded by the image whereas I want the whole body to be backgrounded. If I background the body with the image, the image is splitted in other views(since the views are in the same body) whereas I just want the view1 to be backgrounded by the image.

Any advice?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think putting the background image in the body first and removing it once other views are triggered may be a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First answer works but not for the whole view, just for the div:

What works is :

```
<div style="background:yellow;min-height:100%" id="view0" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/View">
    //whatever you want
</div>
```

What is important is **min-height:100%**

Without it :

[image]

With it :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can style the background of a mobile view using regular CSS.

See the example image below; it shows [this demo](http://demos.dojotoolkit.org/demos/mobileGallery/demo-ios7.html) with the Buttons view selected, styled with a purple background using the Developer Tools. If your background styles are not properly being applied to the view as a whole, please post your code or a snippet of your code that demonstrates the problem, as I suspect your styles are being applied incorrectly.

[image]

Comment: Thanks that's usefull